# Getting dir path in application.yml for folder packaged in Jar

Tags: angular, spring-boot, maven, properties

I have got Spring Boot application, with folder containing Angular frontend. 
I want to get a path to one of the folders in angular frontend. 
Front is builded and packaged to jar via maven. In jar, dir is under `BOOT-INF\classes\static\assets\config`
How can I get the proper path in properties?
simple config-dir:`"BOOT-INF\classes\static\assets\config"` is obviously not working

Comment: The `static` directory is as far as I know a default directory in Spring Boot...?

Comment: So how I can point this path inside jar in application.yml?